# ASP.Net Report Viewer - Same report multiple times with different parameter values

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reportviewer, reporting-services, report-viewer2010

I'm currently working on an ASP.Net WebForms application that allows a user to select an item from a list, which ultimately results in a SSRS report being shown, using Report Viewer 2010 (in server mode). The report has been coded with a parameter `@id` to allow the report to display the correct data for the selected item.

The reports dataset can return multiple rows where some of the data is displayed in a summary area at the top (not in the header section) for example a textbox would have the expression `=FIRST(Fields!Address.Value, "dsMain")`. The data returned is denormalized so Address will always be the same value. Which is why using `FIRST()` works. And the rest of the data is shown in a Tablix with grouping applied etc.

But now I'm looking to change this so users can select multiple items and therefore effectively show the report multiple times, but shown in the same report viewer control. The main requirement is to batch print the reports, so showing it in one report view control is important to allow for one click printing of everything.

Now because I didn't design the report in the first place and because its fairly complex in its layout and the sql that is executed; the sql is geared towards running for one id and not a list of them. I'm looking for options to not have to rewrite the report or the sql.

**Is it possible to give the report viewer the id parameter as a list and let the report viewer execute same report for each id passed?** - I know report parameter can accept multiple values but this isn't the same since the report will unintelligently pass the first value to my stored procedure but not repeat the report for the other values. **Perhaps there's a setting in the report designer that allows it to repeat if it is passed multiple values?**

**Can someone suggest something else to get this working? Or is my only option to extend the report and sql to accept multiple id's and effectively redesign the report?**

Thanks any suggestions or help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use [sub-reports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239314.aspx).

Create a new report that takes a list of ids as a multi valued parameter.

Use that parameter as the dataset for a list control.

Have a subreport inside the list. Report inside the list is your original report.

You can then pass each element of your dataset(your list of parameters) as [parameter to the your sub-report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
SSRS will repeat it as your want.

Comment: Hi, when accepting this as an answer, I tested again prototype reports; container-report and child-reports. Now that I'm trying this for real against production reports I've hit a problem - the header and footer sections are not shown in the sub-reports. Do you know if there is a setting somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: Sadly this is a known limitation. Only the body from sub reports is shown, not headers and footers. See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ba15e779-1de5-4c84-9d14-5739417c0258.